# running a bash file states:date: command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've installed a version of Ubuntu Server and although I'm fairly still fresh with Ubuntu, I'm trying to create a bash file to run a program in the background. More importantly, I'm trying to get a file nameto display correct and create it before I start running the program (I like my debug stuff).

However, here is my bash script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 PATH="/var/log/servers/Game/"
 FILENAME="startup"
 EXT=".log"
 DATE=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)
 NEWFILE=${PATH}${FILENAME}_${DATE}${EXT}
```

I have verified that the file does exist in the PATH directory. However, the issue is with the date command. When I run the script `bash -x game.sh` this is what is displays.

```
 + PATH=/var/log/servers/Game/
 + FILENAME=startup
 + EXT=.log
 ++ date +%d-%m-%Y
 game.sh: line 5: date: command not found
 + DATE=
 + NEWFILE=/var/log/servers/Game/startup_.log
 + echo /var/log/servers/Game/startup_.log
```

I don't understand why it would say the command doesn't work, when I can go to the main console and run `date` and get a valid response.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
PATH="/var/log/servers/Game/"
```

This sets the `PATH` to *just* that directory, and I doubt that directory contains `date`.

Be careful when you use uppercase variable names, you could easily be stomping over a standard environment variable.

Stick to lowercase, and be more descriptive. Consider using, for example:

```
log_path="/var/log/servers/Game/"
NEWFILE="${log_path}${FILENAME}_${DATE}${EXT}"
```

Comment: Wow, now don't I feel like a dummy. X_X. Thank you for this simple solution.